# Making image Blur Using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, canvas, blur

I'm working on JavaScript code to upload, preview, make it blur and download the result image. currently I have done upload and preview code. after that, How to make it blur and download it?

```
    <section class="upload" id="upload">
        <h3>UPLOAD</h3>
      
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          
          <canvas id="c" class="p-3" >Here's the canvas.</canvas>
          <br>
          <input type="file" id="infile" accept = "image/*" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
          <p><img id="output" /></p>
          <button class="btnbl">Blur Image</button>
          <br>
       </div>
     </div>
 
</section>
```

```js
document.getElementById('infile').onchange = function(e) {
          var img = new Image();
          img.onload = draw;
          img.onerror = failed;
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        };
        function draw() {
          var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
          canvas.width = this.width;
          canvas.height = this.height;
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);
        }
        function failed() {
          console.error("The provided file couldn't be loaded as an Image media");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add onclick="blurimg()" to your blur button.
and then add this javascript.

```
function blurimg(){
            document.getElementById("c").style.filter="blur(5px)"
        }
```

Note that I have blurred canvas( id="c")

You can increase or decrease blur(5px) according to your choice

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer on StackOverflow and I am a beginner in web dev so forgive me if I am wrong and correct me instead that would help me too.

I don't know how to do it in Js but in CSS it works like this.

You can use CSS for blur effect as we do in Glassmorphism.
Property: backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
The parameter passed in blur will define the amount of blur that you want. The more it is the more effectively the blur property will work.